# Why is the first PlaySound call from memory delayed a lot in WinAPI?

Tags: windows, winapi, audio, wav, embedded-resource

I am trying to play a WAV resource with low latency.

If I load my audio into memory and then call `PlaySound` with `SND_MEMORY`, then there should be almost no delay, however, there is a huge delay of about one second but if I **rerun the program**, not call the API again, the program behaves fine. After a while, if I don't run it, it will go back to having the delay. The question is why it happens because the code runs **after** the audio is loaded into memory so the load time shouldn't matter.

What my code does is first it loads the audio into memory, then it uses `PlaySound`, and timing-crucial code that needs to sync with the music.

```cpp
HRSRC myResource = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDA_AUDIO), L"WAVE");
DWORD myResourceSize = SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);
HGLOBAL myResourceData = LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
char* xbuffer = (char*) LockResource(myResourceData);

char* bfr = new char[myResourceSize];
memcpy(bfr, xbuffer, myResourceSize);

PlaySoundA(bfr,hInstance,SND_ASYNC|SND_MEMORY);

// timing critical actions here
```

How can I make sure the audio plays consistently, or do I need to use something else?

Comment: Likely a delay in loading the multimedia subsystem if it hasn't already been loaded, or has been unloaded from being unused for awhile. That said, if you need to sync code to audio playback, `PlaySound()` is not the best way to do that

Comment: @RemyLebeau So I discovered that if I play something (eg SND_ALIAS) with SND_SYNC, the "multimedia subsystem" is apparently loaded. That does introduce a delay and a sound, but I guess a quick solution would be to play a silent WAV file although I haven't tried that.

Comment: If you need low-latency and the ability to synchronize with audio, you'll need to use [XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-introduction). Depending on your specific needs, the [Microsoft Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk) might be sufficient.

Comment: @IInspectable would `WaveOutWrite` work? It seems more simple and they all rely on PCM data? I looked at XAudio2 and the code seems to read the WAV manually anyways.

Comment: So I found a really stupid solution, in Audacity I make the WAV 8-bit unsigned at 48,000 sampling rate and I just read the raw file as PCM data, it will play the metadata as audio but it won't really affect anything, this is useful for a extremely quick and dirty solution if you know the audio metadata/can change it. For some reason there still is a delay so I would still need to play a dummy sound in the beginning.